# Adding custom text onto UPS shipping label?

Tags: ups

I want to add a SKU number and Order ID onto the label. Is this possible with UPS's Developer API?

Comment: can you please share full request how to add ReferenceNumber in request/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by filling the **ReferenceNumber** element in the shipment request. You may find the list of available codes in Appendix I in the Shipping documentation.

[image]

Comment: can you please add fulll request how to add ReferenceNumber in request?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **/ShipmentRequest/Shipment/Description** container.

The result will look like something like this:
[image: UPS label examle]